# how to use TeamViewer to start two DIFFERENT session on the same machine?

Tags: teamviewer

I'm playing teamviewer to cooperate with my team.   How can we establish two different sessions for two different windows users on the same computer ? I tried to start a new session on Teamviewer, but it is just replicating the old one, which does not help.

For example,  we have one windows 7 machine which has two users :  A and B.   And we have four people Tom, Bob, Mike, and Leo

How can we start a session on A so that Tom and Bob can work on user A,  while Mike and Leo can work on user B.

Thanks !

Comment: TeamViewer 13 doesn't have this limitation any more. I'm able to have 2 sessions (remote Win 7 PC and remote macOS) on a single Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Windows 7 wasn't designed to handle multiple sessions. This is not a limitation in TeamViewer, but in Windows. It sounds like you want to run 2 desktop sessions on 1 machine. You would need a terminal server environment.

Comment: thanks.  if we migrate to windows server,  would that solve the problem ?

Comment: A Terminal Server, or a Windows Server that allows you to log on with multiple users would solve your problem. Each connected user can then share their session over TeamViewer.

Answer (score 0):

I use TeamViewer 11 on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, Windows 8 Pro 64 bit, and Linux Mint XFce 17.3. My goal was to access Win 7 SQL PC and Linux Apache web server from Windows 8 PC. All I have done was installation of TeamViewer 11 on all three machines and now I can open two different sessions running on my Windows 8 PC.

Answer (score 0):

A). If you are attempting to have multiple sessions out of the one PC then:
In Windows 8/8.1 you can left click or right click on the TeamViewer 11 Task Manager Icon and select the Teamviewer 11 application to open TeamViewer and then you can connect to the remote PC.  Once that first connection is open you can minimise or Alt-Tab away from it and then repeat this step to open more remote sessions.  If you left click you need to click on the first TeamViewer connection panel to start a new session OR if you right-click select the TeamViewer application text in the menu and you can get to the same new connection window. Then once connected to the second (or later) session if you left click on the TeamViewer Task bar icon you will see a horizontal minature windows graphical task switcher style list of all the remote PC session Windows to switch between simply by clicking-on and thus selecting the one you want.

[Multiple TeamViewer Connections (note: the Connection Window is the first one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Ka2.jpg)

B). If you are attempting to have multiple sessions into the same PC (which is what it would appear) then you will have to use Windows Terminal Server or Windows MultiPoint Server.  THis site explains the different scenarios well...
https://www.ncomputing.com/en/WindowsMultiUserLicensing
...or you could one of the cheaper alternatives like thinstuff's xpvs-server (sorry cant add more links)

Answer (score 0):

Using windows10 and Teamviewer11

It is/should be possible, maybe someone with some more technical expertise can work on it. I've proven it is possible to connect with teamviewer to 2 different sessions on one PC. However connecting/reconnecting to the correct session is still a problem.

- If you follow this guideline about the RDPwrapper to allow 2 different sessions to your PC: http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/545-multiple-rdp-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows-10
- Connect Teamviewer
- start an RDP to your internal IP 127.0.0.2
- Connect 2nd Teamviewer

Voila, 2 different sessions. However, you can't minimize the RDP in session1 or teamviewer will loose its connection. Sending it to the background is no problem. If the 'real user' in session1 hits 'show desktop' your 2nd session will disconnect. And teamviewer will only connect to the user that is last logged in, I think. It is very inconsistent.

Another way around this is running a very tiny VMware to log on to with Teamviewer, and than do a RDP from there to your second session.

Or connect teamviewer to a normal VMware. This is very handy if your resolutions of the screens don't match. Using NirCMD u can make shortcuts
to match the resolution of whatever screen you are using.

You can use an program like 'tray-it' to hide the VMware. Maybe it is even possible to start it using task scheduler to run it as SYSTEM (via shortcut, startup, logon or whatever) without GUI (haven't tried this one).

Hope that someone can figure out the decent direct way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect multiple concurrent computers in one target computer. As if you are using 2 mouses and 2 keyboards because I personally tried this scenario. Sample scenario computer A and computer B wants to remotely control computer C at the same time, computer A will login to computer C then computer B will also login to computer C, you can also use your mouse and keyboards of computer A/B at the same time to control the computer C.

Answer (score -1):

In response to Roald van Doorn's answer...
Windows 7 can absolutely handle multiple remote sessions at once.  Multiple remote session capability has been around since the Windows NT 3.5 kernel.  Take a look at RAdmin for example:  http://www.radmin.com/

I use radmin every day.  When I need a vendor to log into a machine and change a some things here and there, I log in and supervise as they also use radmin, log in, and make their changes.  Radmin works on a different OSI layer than Teamviewer does, and this is why this is possible.   It is NOT a limitation of Windows 7, it WAS a limitation of Teamviewer.

Teamviewer 11 absolutely allows multiples on Windows 7.  I'm helping a friend out right now with his father's PC and we are both in using Teamviewer.

Comment: The purpose of an answer is to provide a solution to the original question, rather than to refute another answer.  This claims it can be done, but the question asks how to do it.

Answer (score -2):

The above info is not 100%. Yes it was *desinged* that way, but much like S2012 is designed to allow only 2 concurrent RDC connections, W7 and I assume W8 (I have successfully tested this on W7 x64 Pro) , this can be overridden.

Google "Windows 7 multiple RDC connections" , learning decent Google wording is key to learning and solving new issues :) . For this to work you need to download a small app in the link below and run it.

http://forum.sambapos.com/t/step-by-step-on-how-to-configure-multiple-concurrent-rdp-clients-to-run-sambapos-iphone-ipad-galaxy-tablet/769

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/enable-remote-desktop-connection-in-windows-7-home-premium/

Comment: Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase rather than a collection of links to answers elsewhere.  External links can break, in which case your answer would have no value.  Please incluse the essential information in your answer and use the link just for attribution and further reading.

Comment: Thanx for the input. Link is to show proof VS opinion unlike Roalds post in which he made a statement with no proof that there was no way around the design. There is also an app that needs to be downloaded which is lined in the URL's but I see its now broken.... With the greatest respect, anyone with 1/2 a brain & 1 hand could google the listed *.dll and come right fairly easily, just as I'v just done. :)  Spoon feeding gets one no where :)

http://forum.sambapos.com/t/step-by-step-on-how-to-configure-multiple-concurrent-rdp-clients-to-run-sambapos-iphone-ipad-galaxy-tablet/769

Comment: Please, if possible, describe a little more what the application does and how it works. A direct link would be nice.

Comment: slhck, Im sorry but I dont have time (I run my own business) to really do that. An inquisitive mind will use what resources are available. :)

I see no need to describe what it does as it answers the Q right at the top.  Never found a direct link, only what I posted, for more info Google is your (any my) friend.